# Threshold image using image subtraction using opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, opencv3.0

Can you anyone tell me how to get threshold image using frame differencing
I have an idea about various background subtraction method but i donot want to use them.

cv2.substract(img1,img2) gives this image

[substract:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9gyA.jpg)
[image: Screenshot]

but i want this result [threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GTD3.jpg)
Can anyone tell me how to do that

i donot want to use cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() or such kind function
here is my

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
t=0.01
background=cv2.imread('background2.png')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('car.mp4')
ret,img=cap.read()

avg_img = np.float32(img)
while 1:
    ret,img=cap.read() 
    cv2.accumulateWeighted(img,avg_img,0.1)
    res1 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(avg_img)
    sub_img=cv2.subtract(res1,img)
    cv2.imshow('sub_img',sub_img)
    cv2.imshow('sub_img',sub_img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My opencv version 3.0.0 python 2.7

Comment: Do you have to use cv2? cv2 is great for image processing algorithms that are hard to implement, but in this case the subtraction and thresholding is very simple in numpy.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it using numpy

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: you can perform `cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()` and then follow it up with contour detection using area property?

Comment: Thanks np.abs(img1-img2) works fine

Comment: I'm surprised that np.abs(img1-img2) works fine for your application. Maybe if you keep the conversion to float32 it works out ok. But in general, most images you work with will be np.uint8 and when you do mathematical operations that result in values > 255 or < 0, they will just wrap around -- e.g. 255 + 3 = 2. Most of the OpenCV functions will automatically threshold your values >255 --> 255 and < 0 --> 0. Hence cv2.subtract is expected to have fewer unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are OK with this being done outside of cv2:

```
# Subtraction, assuming img1 and img2 are numpy arrays with same dimension; optionally, use np.abs(img1-img2) if you don't care about the sign of the difference
sub = img1 - img2

# Thresholding
threshold = 128    # Set your threshold value
sub[sub >= threshold] = 255    # Above or equal threshold go to max value
sub[sub < threshold] = 0       # Below threshold go to min value
```

Comment: This solution is elegant and will work well if your data types for img1 and img2 are big enough to handle overflow. Most common image formats are represented by UINT8, so you should first convert to something like INT16 (sub = np.int16(img1) - np.int16(img2)) to handle overflow then after thresholding, sub = np.uint8(sub)